# Caching API Key for application wide use in C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, console-application

I need to use an API key throughout my project(console application) multiple times. Basically I wanted to do this:

- Fetch API key and few other reusable values from local DB
- Cache them somewhere, where I can use them without having to access DB again.

Also caching like this, is it secure? and can the cache be cleared completely before leaving application?
Thanks.

Comment: 1) I understand what you want to achieve, what is your concrete problem in achieving it? Please be specific. 2) There are degrees of security it's difficult to answer that without knowing your context. For example for a web server app that is hosted in a secure data centre and handle the data that is not that sensitive, this might be quite appropriate. If it's a client side app, it's never secure enough to prevent the secret from being extracted.

Answer (score 2):

Use Dependency Injection to pass the thing around, perhaps.
But do you really need it all over your application? This might be a sign of bad design.

Comment: Can you please tell me why it's the sign of bad design. It's an API key that I need to access multiple times in various class files.

Comment: It hints at the violation of encapsulation. If you need a single resource every across your application, then your application is not encapsulating the job needed for that resource very well. It would also make it harder to refactor.

Comment: Can you tell me how can something like API Key(coming from DB), will have availability in multiple classes, each having an isolated functionality?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that your application should only have one "point-of-contact" with the API that you are trying to access. While your parts of your classes may require the API, you can access the API in one place and then cascade the results to those classes, rather than using the API key in each of those classes. In other words, use a single class that knows about the API key as your port-of-call to talk to the actual API. Your other classes can then take that class as a dependency and operate on that.

Comment: The added benefit of doing this sort of thing also makes your application easier to unit test and mock.

Comment: Now I understand clearly. Thanks a lot for the efforts.

Comment: You're welcome. Either way, I would strongly suggest if you do not want to consolidate it into one point of contact, I would suggest you use dependency injection and inject the API key into your classes' constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to store it in a static variable. To be more secure, use [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class

Answer (score 1):

Is it secure? It depends. Were is your process sitting?

(In)security depends entirely on whether is possible (or not) to get access to your process. If someone has access to your process, they can read the key, no matter if you store it statically (though this makes things easier) or you just get it and keep it in memory (on the stack) for the briefest amount of time.

And there is always the chance that your application gets paged out to disk, writing its memory content (including, possibly, the key) on the page file (onto disk). This can happen even if your key is kept only for the current request (if the process is paged out at the wrong time!)

Like others suggested, using a class like SecureString is your best bet; that, and running your process on a machine that is not compromised and secure, of course.

If you need to run it on an arbitrary computer, where a user has administrative access, nothing can really stop the user from reading the key. 
In that case, the weakest link is probably the local database (the user can read the key directly from the DB).

However, using SecureString is a good idea even in this case: its content is encrypted, and further increases the protection (making harder for an attacker to read its plain-text content from the process)

You need however to secure your DB as well, and your DB credentials (which are probably hard-coded in your application, where can be easily read, if again the user/attacker has access to the computer and to your application).

Comment: Very insightful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd997357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) a complete documentation on that topic.

Comment: Generally you don't need a dedicated cache class to store a value or two in an application. A static field or a filed on a singleton object instance will suffice.